# Creating special RSS channels

Tags: 7, feeds

How can I create RSS channels for certain content type or it's subtype (certain taxonomy terms from that content type, so that users can effectively filter the information they need).

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build RSS feeds easily with views, after creating your first display (generally a page), you can click "+Add" and add a feed display, then you configure your fields and you're almost done.
[image: Views feed display]

In the "Filter Criteria" section you select your Content Types and or the taxonomy you want to target.

Comment: I created the RSS channel. But can I display e.g. RSS icon in that block? Or how can I visitors get know that the block has RSS channel and they can subscribe to it? I'd like it to be visible.

Comment: In views 2 there was automatically a RSS icon available at the bottom of the page, I'm not sure how it works for blocks, but you can surely add an HTML footer to your block and paste an `<img>` there with a link to your feed (if of course views doesn't provide an easier way.